# Anybody annoyed by tags that bring up a lot of unrelated questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently removed the [[json]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json?sort=active&pagesize=15) tag from my Interesting Tags on StackOverflow because the majority of the questions marked with this tag have very little to do with JSON itself (example: [REST / SOAP endpoints for a WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186631/rest-soap-endpoints-for-a-wcf-service)).  I know plenty about the nuances of JSON parsing, and a little bit about its typical usage, but questions like the one I linked do not pique my interest, and there are a lot of them.

Hence, in my humble opinion, the [[json]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json?sort=active&pagesize=15) tag on StackOverflow is currently what I'd call an "ill" tag, as most of the questions (perhaps more than 80%) have very little to do with JSON.  On the other hand, the [[c]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c?sort=active&pagesize=15) tag appears to be "healthy", as most of the questions are actually about C.  I speculate that the vast majority of tags on StackExchange are "healthy".

Has anyone else encountered tags like this?  Again, I'm not talking about tags where the occasional off-topic question pops up.  I'm talking about those tags that highlight unrelated posts consistently, to the point where it's annoying.

*PS:  The json tag doesn't really belong on this question, in my opinion.  I'm using it to prove a point :-)*

Comment: Like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074884/remove-thisremove-thisremove-thisremove-thisremove-this

Answer (score 4):

Well, it's great to be an expert at json.  But if you are finding out that you really don't know much about how it is getting used by programmers all over the world, in real applications, then are you really an expert at it?

I contribute to SO to hone my skills in the areas in which I consider myself an expert.  And keeping track and keeping up to speed on how these things are used is rather important to me.  Researching a question about it keeps me informed and knowledgeable and keeps my expertise relevant.  I'm getting back what I put in, works for me.

Comment: *"But if you are finding out that you really don't know much about how it is getting used by programmers all over the world, in real applications, then are you really an expert at it?"* Indeed, that was in the back of my mind when I was writing the question.